# do search in two site and show the result in first site

Tags: php, woocommerce-offtopic

I have two sites the first one is a product search page and the second site is post blog page I want to change the first search to all search field that searches in both site and show the result in the first site.

first WordPress site search field.

[image]

second WordPress site search field.

[image]

how should I add field search in first site and it show both site result?

Both sites powered by WordPress.

I hope someone helps me!

Comment: Welcome to [wordpress.se]. I hope you find the answer(s) you are looking for. Our site is different from most - if you have not done so yet, consider checking out the [tour](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/tour) and [help center](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help) to find out how things work.